# Write media file to internal/external storage

Tags: android, file-io, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am currently trying to figure out a way to write a media file to internal/external storage (primary storage). The file to be saved could be any size from a few MBs to 50MBs. I have logic that works on my Droid X 2.3.3 Razr 2.3.5 (I believe) but does not work on my Galaxy Nexus (has no removable storage but a built in 16Gig card with v4.0.2). I have looked around and haven't found any code/samples that work with v4.0. Maybe I am approaching this all wrong since it doesn't have an actual sd card? maybe it is something new in v4.0? Currently when I run my application on the Galaxy Nexus I get this: *System.err(19520): java.io.FileNotFoundException:*

UPDATED

```
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream(); 
File PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
File FILE = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + FILENAME); 
ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
// buffer int bufferSize = 1024; int bufferLength = 0; byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize]; 
while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) { 
byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength); 
} 
byte[] temp = byteBuffer.toByteArray(); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE); 
fos.write(temp); 
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you putting this file in a specific directory on your sdcard?external storage?

I assume your permissions in your manifest are good because the 'permission denied is not raised' so maybe if you put the file in a specific folder, which is not created you should call the mkdirs() function on your file!

Comment: The value of PATH is /mnt/sdcard

Should I make my own directory, then write the files? I am guessing it does not want me to write to the top most portion of storage??

Comment: Hmm no it was just a question. So, if you do 
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+'/'+nameFile) doesn't work?

Comment: No. If you look up at my original post you can see my current code I am working with. I added what you said and still has not worked. Same exception at the same place. I printed the path to the log file and looks right.

Comment: I'd vote this up if I could. Creating the new directory definitely helped. Why would creating/not creating a dir affect anything? I remember reading somewhere in the Android API it is not recommended but it didn't say it wouldn't work. On the Droid X I was always successfully able to write to the very top most part of the external sd card.

Comment: So do you still have your problem or not? Most of the time I prefer to create a specific directory (even if it is a temporary one) to put files generated by my app in it.

Comment: No I don't have the problem. Your suggestion seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't convert it to a string, just use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` as a `File`:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sd, FILENAME);
```

I don't know if that will correct it or not, but it wouldn't hurt to try that. And you do not need to call `file.createNewFile()` before writing to the file with a `FileOutputStream`. The docs about [`FileOutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) say:

> An output stream that writes bytes to a file. If the output file
>   exists, it can be replaced or appended to. If it does not exist, a new
>   file will be created.

And which line of code is the `FileNotFoundException` happening on?

Comment: InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
  
  File PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  File FILE = new File(PATH, FILENAME);
  
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  
  // buffer
  int bufferSize = 1024;
  int bufferLength = 0;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
  
  while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
  }
  
  byte[] temp = byteBuffer.toByteArray();
  
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE);
  fos.write(temp);
  fos.close();

Comment: The exception is being thrown on this line:
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

Comment: Okay. So if it fails on `urlConnection.getInputStream()` then you have an error in the code prior to that where you set up the `URLConnection`.

Comment: Understandable, but hard to believe. Like I said my application works on other devices. I am going to try to mesh together the new file io stuff with the current urlConnection logic and see what happens.

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError @
    byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

in...

while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) { byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
}