# Why is file not being written to the internal storage?

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am trying to create a text file and fill it with some data. Exception is being generated as shown in the code below. The file isn't getting saved and exception is generated. What is wrong with my code?

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.*;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String fileName = "thisdata.txt";
    String text = "8934759034850938450348509";


    try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
        writer.append(text);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been written to Report File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data has not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    }
}
```

My manifest files have these two lines.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application does not write file to internal storage \[Android\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235882/application-does-not-write-file-to-internal-storage-android)

Comment: Are you trying this on Android 10? If yes Filenames are worthless outside of your App's private directories, use MediaStore or Storage Access Framework instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write media file to internal/external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825242/write-media-file-to-internal-external-storage)

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet you are not creating a file, but simply passing a random String as file name into the FileWriter's constructor.
If you want to create the file inside your own app (Accessible only by your app), you can create the file as below.Or if you are not sure where to create the file, pls refer [this article from dev.android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/)

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"thisdata.txt");
 String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath() ;
String text = "8934759034850938450348509";


try
{
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
    writer.append(text);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data has been written to Report File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data has not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```